# How does Laravel know about Middlewares of packages by auto discovery?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, middleware, laravel-5.5

Searched for this information and I couldn't find anything. Only github links and some info but about service providers not middlewares.

I saw something about registering middlewares in service providers, but it's not the point.

I mean.

This package - [laravel-page-speed](https://github.com/renatomarinho/laravel-page-speed)

As I read, auto discovery takes registration of service providers from composer.json.

Okay, but there is no word about middlewares.

So maybe this package?

```
public function boot()
    {
        $this->publishes([
            __DIR__.'/../config/laravel-page-speed.php' => config_path('laravel-page-speed.php'),
        ]);
    }
    /**
     * Register the service provider.
     */
    public function register()
    {
        $this->mergeConfigFrom(__DIR__.'/../config/laravel-page-speed.php', 'laravel-page-speed.php');
    }
```

I don't see anything about middlewares, so maybe this config? I won't put here all the code, but too, nothing about it. Just enable package and skipped extensions.

So how?

This package uses and brings in several middlewares, but doesn't register them anywhere.

Without auto-discovery we need to type them on our own. But with auto discovery we haven't and I don't see anywhere in the package to register them.

So just I need explanation how this works.

How this middlewares actually are registered to work?

Comment: are you actually sure those middleware got registered at all or are you assuming based on what the documentation on that page says?

Comment: @lagbox assumed based on documentation. Documentation said so. But I think is a bug in it.
Tried this one now. Doesn't work at all without addind list of middlewares from this package to kernel. On 5.5.27. So that's I think broken package. Although service provider of this package is registered well (checked with dd(1)), so its a bug I think

Comment: yea that was what i was hinting at, it doesn't register them, the documentation just doesn't read right, you will still need to register those middleware in the kernel ... perhaps contact that package maintainer about the issue with the documentation

Answer (score 1):

I don't think those extra middlewares are auto-registered. Looking at Github documentation you could think so but I believe this is only matter of not best markdown formatting for readme because in case you would like to publish configuration file you still need to run:

```
php artisan vendor:publish --provider="RenatoMarinho\LaravelPageSpeed\ServiceProvider"
```

although you could think you need to do it only in Laravel < 5.5

Comment: I have Laravel 5.5.27.

Comment: Tried this one now. Doesn't work at all without addind list of middlewares from this package to kernel. On 5.5.27. So that's I think broken package. Although service provider of this package is registered well (checked with dd(1)), so its a bug I think

Comment: @KrystianPolska I believe https://github.com/renatomarinho/laravel-page-speed#publish-configuration-file and next sections of readme apply to all Laravel versions (including 5.5) so to publish configuration or use middlewares you need to do what is written here

Comment: I think the same, but documentation states something else + 'on 5.5 - You don't have to do anything else'

Comment: @KrystianPolska I believe author mean adding service provider and if you see middlewares are not automatically working in 5.5 I believe midldewares are not auto-registered as I said in my answer

Answer (score 0):

At current Date (08.2018) they're **not** auto registered in this package you mention (laravel-page-speed).

I know two ways to register middlewares in Laravel 5.6 from within a package.

This will push the middleware to the global $middlewares array from App\Http\Kernel and will be executed **before** the route middleware groups ($middlewareGroups e.g. 'web').

```
$kernel = app()->make(Kernel::class);
$kernel->pushMiddleware(YourMiddleware::class);
```

This will push the middleware to the route middleware groups array from App\Http\Kernel $middlewareGroups and will be executed **after** the global $middlewares:

```
$router = app()->make(Router::class);
$router->pushMiddlewareToGroup('web', YourMiddleware::class);
```

So that means if you need to access the session, you need to push it to the middelwareGroups.

Hope it helps someone.